# autocomplete query does not show list which is in another jsp but show list if we write down on same page

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp, autocomplete

In this Jsp code, I don't get any error when source is given as 'a','b' etc but it shows nothing when using another jsp like this

```
$('#cname').autocomplete({
source: 'list1.jsp',
select: function (event, ui) {
    var env_id = ui.value;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'dc_ajax.jsp',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            count: env_id
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $('#dc').html("data: " + data);
        },
        error: function () {
            $('#dc').html('<p class="error"><strong>Oops!</strong> Try that again in a few moments.</p>');
        }
    });
}
```

});

Here is my list1.jsp code

```
ResultSet rs=st1.executeQuery("SELECT distinct c.cust_name AS cust FROM cust_mast c join env_mast e join service_mast s where c.cust_id=e.cust_id and e.service_id=s.service_id");
        List<String> li = new ArrayList<String>();
        while(rs.next()) 
        {               
            li.add(rs.getString(1));

        }
        String[] str = new String[li.size()];           
        Iterator<String> it = li.iterator();
        int i = 0;
        while(it.hasNext())
        {
            String p = (String)it.next();   
            str[i] = p;
            i++;
        }
        //jQuery related start      
            String query = (String)request.getParameter("q");
        System.out.println(query);

            int cnt=1;
            for(int j=0;j<str.length;j++)
            {
                if(str[j].toUpperCase().startsWith(query.toUpperCase()))
                {
                out.print(str[j]+"\n");
                    if(cnt>=5)
                        break;
                    cnt++;
                }
            }
```

Is this problem in jquery or new Jsp? Please suggest what should be done for it?

Comment: Any errors in the console ?

Comment: no it doesn't show any error, but don't display a list

Comment: have you checked the response in the console ? check what you are getting ?